# Phonegap screen dimension (android)

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, cordova

I made HTML5 application for Android using Phonegap.
Phone dimension is 480 x 800. Javascript returns screen width 480 (screen.width). But content with 480px width are bigger than screen. When I hard code this element with width = 320 it looks good.

For example:

```
<div style="width:480px;border:#000000 1px solid">It's bigger than screen</div>            
<div style="width:320px;border:#000000 1px solid">It's looking good</div>
```

Which way I should use to get width? Or there's some config params in Phonegap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
csswidth = screen.width / window.devicePixelRatio
```

To get CSS width we have to divide screen width ('cause it's fullscreen app) by device pixel ratio.

480/1.5=320. All right.

Comment: Please edit your answer, and explain why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Read this article to understand : http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

480 is the width in physical pixels of your device, 320 is the css width of the page. It's a trick to make your page display the same way on devices of same size and having different densities.